# Add count to N1QL query result in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a N1QL query:

```
SELECT p.`ID`, p.`Name` FROM `Preferences` p WHERE `type` = "myType"
```

The result is a list of objects`[{"ID": "123", "Name": "John"}, ...]`

I want to get a result JSON such as:

```
{
  "count": 5, 
  "result": [{"ID": "123", "Name": "John"}, ...]
}
```

How could I do this using N1QL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   COUNT(t.ID) AS count,
   ARRAY_AGG(t) AS results
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        p.`ID`, p.`Name`
      FROM
       `Preferences` p 
      WHERE `type` = "myType"
    ) AS t
```